# CSV download not showing exact values

Tags: python, csv

Output for my python code is as follows:

```
Anger 0.129971
Disgust 0.119636
Fear 0.216546
Joy 0.301672
Sadness 0.54521
Analytical 0.0
Confident 0.0
Tentative 0.0
Openness 0.817
Conscientiousness 0.571
Extraversion 0.157
Agreeableness 0.012
Emotional Range 0.401
```

where text denotes the variable tone_name and decimal denotes the score in following code

I have been running following code to dump the output in a CSV file:

```
file = glob.glob(path)
# iterate over the list getting each file 
#writer = csv.writer(open('our-merged-data', mode='w')) 
for fle in file:
    # open the file and then call .read() to get the text 
    with open(fle) as f:

        data=tone_analyzer.tone(text='text')

    # iterate through tone analysis data
    tonename=[]; tonescore=[]
    for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
     for tone in cat['tones']:
             tonename.append(tone['tone_name'])
             tonescore.append(tone['score'])
             print(tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])
    # output tone name and score to file
    output = fle.replace('.html', '')     
    X=output
    with open(X+'_tonename.csv', mode = 'w') as csvfile1:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile1) 
        for i in tonename:
            writer.writerows((tone['tone_name'],tone['score']) for tone in cat['tones'])
```

Not sure why but when I open output CSV I dont see all the values of the output, instead all I see is something as follows:

```
Openness    0.817

Conscientiousness   0.571

Extraversion    0.157

Agreeableness   0.012

Emotional Range 0.401

Openness    0.817

Conscientiousness   0.571

Extraversion    0.157

Agreeableness   0.012

Emotional Range 0.401

Openness    0.817

Conscientiousness   0.571

Extraversion    0.157

Agreeableness   0.012
```

Not sure why my output is not being completely appended to CSV and I would really appreciate any help with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've assigned `cat` to every element of `data['document_tone']['tone_categories']` in the for-loop. When you then exit the for-loop, `cat` will refer to the **last** element in that list. That means that `cat` is a subset of the data you want.

Next, in the codeblock where you are writing the csv-file, you're iterating over `tonename`, which is exactly as long as the data you're interested in, but you're not actually using the elements of that `tonename` list, which you want. For that reason, you're repeating elements in your output file, because you're getting the elements of `cat` and writing them the same number of times as the amount of elements in `tonename`. It's a bit like writing this:

```
tonenames = ["a", "b", "c"]
cat = tonenames[-1]
for tname in tonenames:
    print(cat)
```

A bit at least, I hope you see the analogy.

What you're interested in is this:

```
for fin in glob.glob(path):
    with open(fin) as f:
        # you're missing some code here - I've taken the next two lines from your previous stackoverflow posts by guessing
        text = f.read()
        data = tone_analyzer.tone(text)

    tonenames = []; tonescores = [];
    for cat in data['document_tone']['tone_categories']:
        for tone in cat['tones']:
            tonenames.append(tone['tone_name'])
            tonescores.append(tone['score'])
            print(tone['tone_name'],tone['score'])

    outfile = fin.replace('.html', '_tonename.csv')  
    with open(outfile, mode = 'w') as csvfile1:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile1) 
        writer.writerows((name, score) for name, score in zip(tonenames, tonescores))
```

Might I suggest that, given the nature of the other questions you've made here on StackOverflow on essentially the same programming problem, that you check some of those answered questions out and take action on the comments the others have asked? Some of them are waiting for your answer or for more input and others can be closed, by you checking the tickmark next to their answer (if you think it's solved your question).

Comment: Thank you, so much for explaining, this worked perfectly I really appreciate you help and thanks a lot for the advise I will certainly keep that in mind.

Comment: @Rvs, glad this is working so well for you. If you consider this particular question resolved, don't forget to mark the answer that solved it, by clicking the green checkmark next to it. And there's a few more of your questions that are seemingly resolved as well, you could have a look at those too?